# How many ways can we distribute $r$ identical balls into $n$ distinct boxes with exactly $m$ boxes empty

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are $\binom{r+n-1}{n-1}$ ways for distributing $r$ identical balls into $n$ distinct boxes. The $m$ part is throwing me off. I would say there are $\binom{r+n-m-1}{n-m-1}$ ways, but I'm not sure if I'm right.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

See the above table with all the required combinations

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite correct. Think about it as a two-stage process:

- choose the empty boxes: $\binom nm$ ways
- put the $r$ balls into $n-m$ boxes: $\binom{r+n-m-1}{n-m-1}$ ways, as you wrote

So your answer is off, but only by a factor of $\binom nm$.

Comment: we're looking for exactly $m$ boxes empty, so after fixing empty boxes in $C(n,m)$ ways, we want to solve $x_1 + x_2 \ldots x_{n-m} = r$ where $x_i \geq 1 \; \forall 1\leq i \leq n-m$ which gives $C(r-1,n-m-1)$

Comment: I agree with Abhay.  When you put the balls into the boxes you are not allowed to have any empty, so you are selecting from $r-1$, not $r+n-m-1$.  The latter would be correct if you were allowed to have some more boxes empty.