# UPDATE:How many ways can we distribute $r$ identical balls into $n$ distinct boxes with exactly $m$ boxes empty

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

> How many ways can we distribute $r$ identical balls into $n$ distinct
>   boxes with exactly $m$ boxes empty

we're looking for exactly $m$ boxes empty.

So after fixing empty boxes in $C(n,m)$ ways, we want to solve $x_1 + x_2 \ldots x_{n-m} = r$ where $x_i \geq 1 \; \forall 1\leq i \leq n-m$ which gives $C(r-1,n-m-1)$

So answer should be $C(n,m)*C(r-1,n-m-1)$

which doesn't agree with one of the answers [on this post:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957334/how-many-ways-can-we-distribute-r-identical-balls-into-n-distinct-boxes-with)

So which is the correct answer?

Comment: The question says that none of the boxes is to be empty, and has no mention of $m$.  Where do you get, "We're looking for exactly $m$ empty boxes?"

Comment: The post has identical balls and your has distinct and same problem with the boxes

Comment: Sorry, wrong title, it's been updated. check now. I mis-typed the title at first.

Comment: Yes, yours is correct.  I have commented on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

After fixing $m$ empty boxes ($n\choose m$ ways), and one ball in each of the other $n-m$ boxes (one way), you have $r-(n-m)$ balls remaining to put freely into $n-m$ boxes, and the [stars and bars formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) gives you $${[r-(n-m)]+[n-m]-1\choose [n-m]-1}={r-1\choose n-m-1}\text{ ways}$$